# JavaScript Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a complex function that loops through the elements during the onSuccess: of my js and I'm getting the following error that I haven't seen before.

```
exception encountered : {"message": "Invalid argument.", "description": "Invalid argument.", "number": -2147024809, "name": "Error"}
```

The js function looks like this:

```
if(Object.isArray(list)){
     list.each(function(listItem, index){
         if(!Object.isUndefined(listItem.disabled)){
              listItem.disabled = disableFlag;
         }
     });
}
```

that is called from the onSuccess: portion of an Update. My html is a button that is calling the noted function from an onclick.  When I run it the onException: always happens and I'm getting the error by:

```
Object.toJSON(exception)
```

Has anyone seen this before? I have tried playing around with the functionality and it seems that when I use the button to do what it's supposed to do after a specific sequence of events is the only time this happens. So, I placed an arbitrary link on the page and wanted to see if I clicked that, what would happen and it updated the JSON object on the page and allowed for me to use the button for it's set action without the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java? Does this even involve Java (taking into account that Javascript!=Java)?

Comment: What line of code throws the exception?

Comment: It seems to be when I come out of this embeded function. It's inside a double loop with both objects only having one each so this function is only called once and then the error is thrown and it doesn't complete additional lines of code to process the functionality.

Comment: Maybe try `list.forEach` instead of `list.each`?

Comment: Which line causes the problem? Have you commented out each function in turn & seen when the error stops happening?

Comment: the error you are getting doesn't look like a javascript error, i'd look to the server-side code for answers.

Comment: Dan I tried that and got that the 'property or method wasn't supported'.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this kind of error happens in IE when you set an attribute of a DOM element.

If `listItem` is DOM element then maybe it's not yet added to the document or `disableFlag` is an invalid value. Or the error happens outside the provided code.

Comment: I agree that it could be that the DOM element has not yet been added to the document. I would like to know if there is a way to prompt js to add the DOM element before? Thank you by the way.

Comment: If you know exactly where the error happens just add a `try / catch` block. When the exception is thrown you can add the element in the `catch` handler.